# Google Analytics - Data Feed Query Explorer

Tags: google-analytics

The link for the data feed query explorer http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html says that I need to provide a table id, of the format ga:1234 if my table id is 1234. Where do I get my table IDs from. There is only one ID I can see when I visit my Google Analytics site, that starts with UA-XXXXXX-X (X are some digits).

Answer (score 1):

The Data Feed Query Explorer shows the table ID once you give it approval to access your GA data.

[image]

But, you can find the table ID also known as the `profile` ID in the Admin settings:

Go to `Admin` (upper left), click on `Profile Settings` under the profile name. It will be listed as `Profile ID`.

[image]